# what is the best way to save PIL image in json

Tags: python, json, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to send json dict that should contain Pillow image as one of his fields, to do that I have to convert the image to string.
I tried to use pillow function:
`image.toString()`
but still got it as bytes, so I tried to encode it:

```
buff = BytesIO()
image.save(buff, format="JPEG")
img_str = base64.b64encode(buff.getvalue())
```

but still got it as bytes.
How can I convert Pillow images to format that can be saved in json file?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You now have your data as a string, and you want to save your data in a json file, and json files are capable of saving strings. So what's the problem? Save your string to the file.

Comment: Maybe this `jstr = json.dumps({"image": base64.b64encode(buff.getvalue()).decode('ascii')})`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the comments, Mark Setchell suggests calling `.decode('ascii')` on the result of your `b64encode` call. I agree that this will work, but I think base64encoding to begin with is introducing an unnecessary extra step that complicates your code.*

Instead, I suggest directly decoding the bytes returned by `image.tostring`. The only complication is that the bytes object can contain values larger than 128, so you can't decode it with `ascii`. Try using an encoding that can handle values up to 256, such as `latin1`.

```
from PIL import Image
import json

#create sample file. You don't have to do this in your real code.
img = Image.new("RGB", (10,10), "red")

#decode.
s = img.tobytes().decode("latin1")

#serialize.
with open("outputfile.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(s, file)
```

(*but, to my surprise, the resulting json file is still smaller than one made with a latin1 encoding, at least for my sample file. Use your own judgement to determine whether file size or program clarity is more important.)

Comment: I'm not wishing to argue or disagree with you, as I am here to learn as much as the next man. I think that the JPEG encoding is maybe a far more critical factor in reducing size than any concerns about base64 efficiency. A colour image of 3000x4000px is 36MB, but maybe only 300kB JPEG encoded where an extra 30% of base64 inefficiency making 400kB is dwarfed by omitting the JPEG step. As I said, I am here to learn and may be wrong - I'm pretty new to Python and JSON and happy to see the other side of solutions and learn.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Good observation. I agree that saving as JPEG could result in considerable improvements in memory. My sample code uses `tobytes()` instead of `image.save(buff, format="JPEG")` because it's slightly more concise. But it's not essential to my answer; the OP should feel free to continue using their BytesIO strategy, regardless of whether they go with a b64-and-ascii encoding or a latin1 encoding.

Comment: Cool - thank you for taking time to clarify. You already have my vote.

Answer (score 7):

I use the following to exchange Pillow images via json.

```
import json
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

filename = "filename.jpeg"
image = Image.open(filename)
json_data = json.dumps(np.array(image).tolist())
new_image = Image.fromarray(np.array(json.loads(json_data), dtype='uint8'))
```